# How to \label emails in appendix?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, cross-referencing

I would like to include ~20 emails in the appendix section of an article, so I in the article can e.g. write "...according to `\ref{email1}`".

If I put each email in a subsection, then I have to find a name for each of them, which I don't really want.

Each email is enclosed in `\begin{verbatim} \end{verbatim}`.

Is there a way to `\ref` these emails?

Comment: You presumably need some kind of heading or tag so the cross reference has some visible reference to the email? If so you could just use `\label` as normal?

Comment: Yes, something like that would be great. A bit like how equations work with `\label` and `\ref`.

Comment: But what I mean is your question isn't clear. A verbatim on its own has nothing (in the final output) to use as a reference, but if they are titled or numbered or marked in any way then most likely `\label` would just work. You probably need to give more indication of the required result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\newcounter{quotedemail}
\newenvironment{quotedemail}[1]
 {\refstepcounter{quotedemail}\label{#1}%
  \subsubsection*{Email message \thequotedemail}
  \verbatim}
 {\endverbatim}

\begin{document}
As we read in the quoted email message \ref{email1} ...

\begin{quotedemail}{email1}
From: foo@bar.baz
To: Sandra

Got it!

foo
\end{quotedemail}

\end{document}
```

[image]